# meteor mrt collectionfs deploy

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite

I use collectionfs for storing files in my application.

I copy+pasted most of the readme code provided with collectionfs into my application and also added the

```
{{cfsFileUrl "default1"}}
```

to my file listing. Everything works on my local machine.

The problem arises when I deploy to ???.meteor.com with

```
mrt deploy ???.meteor.com
```

I can upload and download images and also a url is displayed from cfsFileUrl,

BUT:

When I access that url, I get Error 404.

My code:
client.html

```
<body>
    {{loginButtons}}
    {{>queueControl}}
    <br>ta
    <br>
    {{>fileTable}}
</body>

<template name="queueControl">
    <h3>Select file(s) to upload:</h3>
    <input name="files" type="file" class="fileUploader" multiple>
</template>

<template name="fileTable">
    {{#each files}}
    {{cfsDownloadButton "ContactsFS" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini" content=filename}}<br>
        <img src="{{cfsFileUrl "default1"}}">
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

client.js

```
ContactsFS = new CollectionFS('contacts', { autopublish: false });

Deps.autorun(function () {
    Meteor.subscribe('myContactsFiles');
});

Template.queueControl.events({
    'change .fileUploader': function (e) {
        var files = e.target.files;
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            ContactsFS.storeFile(f);
        }
    }
});

Template.fileTable.files = function() {
    //show all files that have been published to the client, with most recently uploaded first
    return ContactsFS.find({}, { sort: { uploadDate:-1 } });
};
```

server.js

```
ContactsFS = new CollectionFS('contacts', { autopublish: false });

Meteor.publish('myContactsFiles', function() {
    if (this.userId) {
        return ContactsFS.find({ owner: this.userId }, { limit: 30 });
    }
});

ContactsFS.allow({
    insert: function(userId, file) { return userId && file.owner === userId; }
});

ContactsFS.fileHandlers({
  default1: function(options) { // Options contains blob and fileRecord — same is expected in return if should be saved on filesytem, can be modified
    console.log('I am handling default1: ' + options.fileRecord.filename);
     console.log(options.destination());
    return { blob: options.blob, fileRecord: options.fileRecord }; // if no blob then save result in fileHandle (added createdAt)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and posted it on collectionfs issue page. Check it out: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/issues/85